# console.log() not appearing in output for express server

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get console.log() to appear with my express server. It's a middle-tier API for our front-end. You'll have to forgive me if I speak about it a little awkwardly, I'm relatively inexperienced with these tools but I'll do my best to explain the issue despite my inexperience. I'm trying to use console.log to get a better idea of a rather complex projects behavior and what might be causing some issues with it in its current state. Unfortunately console.log only seems to work within plainjane examples like so:

```typescript
export const routerExample = express.Router();
    
routerExample.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Time: ', Date.now()); // I show up in console just fine
    next();
});
```

When I try to lookup the problem I'm experiencing all solutions seem to be regarding getting routing examples like the one above to appear in console, I can see such examples just fine. The problem comes from getting anything to show up in examples like:

```js
// routing.ts
import { homeController } from '../controllers/homeController';

const homeEx: HomeExample = new HomeExample();

routerExample.get('/home', homeEx.getHome);
```

```typescript
// homeController.ts
export class HomeExample {
    public getHome (req: Request, res: Response) : void {
        console.log("something is happening");
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Any uses of console.log like above never appear anywhere in node's console (or elsewhere as far as I can tell).

What am I missing that is needed to make these log messages appear? This has to be incredibly simple but I've been through *numerous* similar sounding issues on stackoverflow and elsewhere and everything single of one of them seems to be describing slightly different issues (or misunderstandings) that don't solve my own issue. I've tried numerous versions of node/npm and have added the DEBUG:* flag as well. None of this seems to solve it. If I'm missing any code that'd help give context to the issue let me know. I've obviously cut down parts and renamed some objects as I can't exactly dump work-related code here. What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit 1: since many similar posts to this seem to get this mixed up, no I'm not looking at my front-end's console or something for the output. I'm looking in the terminal window where I start the server from, where the router example does appear.

Edit 2: for reference, my file structure is something like:

- app/

  - controllers/

    - homeController.ts (HomeExample stuff is here)
  - routes

    - routing.ts (routerExample stuff is here)
  - app.ts
  - ...

Edit 3: the code works overall to be clear. the problem is explicitly that that log.console() isn't appearing, all the code I've wrapped into "// do stuff" is working as expected.

Comment: How is `routerExample` hooked up?  And, what request are you sending to your server that is supposed to trigger that route?  We can't really help find your routing problem if you don't show the entire path from your express `app` object all the way to the route in question.  And, please don't make up code just for the purposes of the question.  Please include your REAL code, as much as necessary to illustrate the full code path in question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a fresh nights sleep I've figured it out. It, of course, was the most obvious problem that managed to slip by me in the overall complexity of the codebase. The `/home` call was deprecated and replaced with a different call in the front-end without mention in the middle-tier code that I had posted. I didn't even consider checking what was being called any deeper since I was experiencing the same issue with multiple other calls that I didn't include in the original post for brevity. Basically all the tools I'm working with here are completely new to me so my inexperience got the best of me. Thank you to @jfriend00 who made me double-take how `/home` was being called (it wasn't).

**Since I was getting the data I needed without issue** on the front-end **I assumed these functions were being run**, seeing as the data they produced was the same kind of data that was successfully being shown by the front-end, just without the console.log() output I added appearing.

Moral of the story: if every other question related to an issue on Stack Overflow concludes with "I just made a dumb mistake," take absolutely every precaution possible to observe what's happening, even if you feel like you already ruled out certain possibilities. Unfortunately I got a bit caught up with all the weird solutions I saw to the point where I got ahead of myself in debugging the problem.

I'm still a bit confused since the `/home` call specifically should still be "active" even if not called by the front-end, but console.log() is clearly working on other similar functions I've tested since figuring this out. There's either something hidden deep in the codebase that's breaking/overwriting `/home` and other old calls, or it's simply not being called right when I'm testing it outside of the front-end.

TLDR: I'm an idiot, every single API call I thought I was testing was not actually being called. Double-check your assumptions before asking for a specific solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [Express Middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

```
routerExample.get('/home', homeExample);

function homeExample (req: Request, res: Response, next:NextFunction) : void {
         console.log("something is happening");
         // do stuff
     }
}
```

You are also calling a member of a non static or instantiated class see this:
[TypeScript - Static](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-static)

Comment: Hey I tried your suggestion but it doesn't seem to have resolved the issue. I'm probably just misunderstanding what you're suggesting. Could you clarify what you mean in the last part of your answer ("You are also calling a member of a ...")?

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is to create a new instance of the `homeExample` class. What I recommend is to export the new instance on the route file like this:

`/routes/home.route.js`

```js
class HomeRoute {
  /* your methods */
}

export default new HomeRoute();
```

then you can use it:

```js
import homeRoutes from './routes/home.route';

router.get('/home', homeRoutes.getHome);
```

See the example:

https://replit.com/@abranhe/expressjs-console-log#index.js

Comment: My sincere apologies for the confusion but after seeing your answer I'm now realizing my code already had that. The original class having an identical name to the instance was just a mistake I made when transcribing the code to stack overflow. I've edited the original post to reflect how my code is actually written. Sorry again for the confusion.